# bootstrap responsive menu button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here is my link:
http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com/

For some reason when I get the responsive button menu, it does nothing. I have changed the css to allow me to activate the hover drop down on the larger menu items. What would cause this responsive menu to not work?

---

No dice. Here what I have noticed...when I change this code:

`<div class="row-fluid brand-nmg text-center">
                                <a id="logo" title="" href="http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com">
                                                                            <img src="http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo.png" alt="">
                                        </a></div>`

to this:
`<div class="brand-nmg text-center">
                                <a id="logo" title="" href="http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com">
                                                                            <img src="http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo.png" alt="">
                                        </a></div>`

The button works. Any idea why the "row-fluid" would not allow me to click? I have tried several z-index mods with no luck.

Comment: It is better to isolate the problem with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), as your link may not exist in the future (not to mention people may not want to open random links).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't written your navbar code properly to conform with what Bootstrap expects to happen. Look at the Bootstrap example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Specifically, it looks like you are missing the `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">` wrapper.

Comment: I Tried that but no luck. Here is what I did find...when I change this code:

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was the 100% width set by the row-fluid. I removed the row-fluid and set my width according to the screen size to be less that 100% and all is working now:)

Comment: Don't forget you can mark your own answer as correct in case anyone else finds this problem.